# Why is code compiled in g++ so significantly faste than in microsoft compiler?

Tags: c++, vector, g++

I have the following code that using g++ runs 3 seconds, under microsoft compiler runs over 30 seconds and I dont understand...

```
struct constraint{
    int bitline;
    int result;
};  

// this vector is filled with about 1 milion items
vector<constraint> constraints;

for (int a = 0; a < constraints.size(); ++a)
{
    if (a% 100 == 0) cout << a << " "<<endl;
    for (int b = a; b < constraints.size(); ++b)
    {
        int anded = constraints[a].bitline & constraints[b].bitline;
        int ored =  constraints[a].bitline | constraints[b].bitline;

        // a subset of b
        if (anded == constraints[a].bitline && constraints[a].result >= constraints[b].result )
        {
            // delete a
            constraints[a].bitline = 0;
        }
        if (anded == constraints[b].bitline && constraints[b].result >= constraints[a].result )
        {
            constraints[b].bitline = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: I use no optimalization flags, withing. Run on windows xp 32 bit... Tried it without the "debug cout line" - no significant change.

Comment: GCC is probably not always 10 times faster than MSVC.

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: The difference might be the optimisation used or cout may be slow in msvc for some reason. Can you post you command lines and also retry without the 'cout << ...' line?

Comment: What's your benchmark? What are your compiler flags?

Comment: You forgot to mention optimization flags and OS's versions (32 vs 64--bit).

Comment: so you are really thinking MS can produce a compiler 10 time slower than GCC and not investing one dollar to improve it? wouldn't be easy to guess your benchmark is wrong somewhere? There is no optimization nor platform 32/64 justifying this

Comment: @FelicePollano well I run it on the same input - where did I go wrong then?

Comment: @Novellizator maybe using bitline and result to random values?

Comment: Don't EVER use unoptimized code for benchmarks. In particular `std::vector<T> operator[](size_type x)` contains code to check that you are not going outside the vector. Which I believe isn't the case in gcc (which, if you don't give it any optimization option actually uses -O1.

Comment: @MatsPetersson thanks for the answer! I rewrote the code to use array instead of vector and suddently both codes were about same fast...

Comment: Yes, and if you enable optimization, you would find that it's also the same speed, I'm sure.

Comment: @MatsPetersson gcc uses -O0 by default - see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: @MatsPetersson, as the comment above says, gcc defaults to `-O0` not `-O1`, but you're right it doesn't use checked iterators and range checking by default, you have to use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for that

Comment: I guess you were downvoted by MVSC++ fans)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

First, while MSVC++ does have its flaws, the performance of its generated code is not generally considered to be bad.

Second, use the "are the compiler writers braindead" test. How incredibly dumb would Microsoft's engineers have to be, to make a compiler which is **ten** times as slow as the competitor, and not work to improve it? 10% or even 50% could be explained by "Microsoft's compiler just generates crap code", but 1000%? Probably not. So you should look elsewhere for the explanation. :)

And the explanation is simple:

your benchmark is not testing how fast code is generated by the two compilers.
You are testing which compiler inserts the most debug checks when optimizations are disabled, when you are explicitly telling the compiler *"no, it's good, take your time, I don't care how slow the executable is, I just want it to be easy to use for debugging purposes"*.

And when given these instructions, Microsoft inserts more additional correctness checks and run-time checking than GCC does. Thus, its executable becomes slower.

When benchmarking, rule 1 is **always enable optimizations**.

Anything else is like trying to measure who's the fastest runner *without telling the competitors that they're supposed to run*. The guy who went into the kitchen to make a sandwich instead of heading towards the goal isn't necessarily a slower runner, he just didn't get any instructions that he should run towards the goal.

The biggest offender (but not the only one) in your code is *probably* that on MSVC in debug builds, `operator[]` on a vector contains additional range checks. But despite that, the correct answer is not "oh, I'll just stop using `std::vector`", but "oh, maybe I should enable optimizations" in the instances where I care about speed.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the case. One of GCC's flaws is that it doesn't do anywhere near as much debug checking as Microsoft's compiler when compiling without optimizations.